Querydls Case When enum: Could not determine ValueMapping for SqmParameter
I have a query made with querydsl, in the query I extract a field as an enum, but running the query it throws this error:
org.hibernate.query.sqm.sql.ConversionException: Could not determine ValueMapping for SqmParameter: SqmPositionalParameter(2)

The problem seems related to the conversion of the enum. The query is something like this:
query.select(new QTestDto(qTE.id,
           Expressions.cases()
                      .when(qTE.code.startsWith("A"))
                      .then(TestType.GOOD)
                      .otherwise(TestType.BAD)))
     .from(qTE)
     .fetch();

If I change the projected objects TestDto, using a string instead an enum, and I change the extraction with toString(), it works, but I would like to use directly the enum.
This is a unit test to reproduce the error:
import com.querydsl.core.annotations.QueryProjection;
import com.querydsl.core.types.ConstructorExpression;
import com.querydsl.core.types.Path;
import com.querydsl.core.types.PathMetadata;
import com.querydsl.core.types.dsl.EntityPathBase;
import com.querydsl.core.types.dsl.Expressions;
import com.querydsl.core.types.dsl.NumberPath;
import com.querydsl.core.types.dsl.StringPath;
import com.querydsl.jpa.impl.JPAQuery;
import jakarta.persistence.Column;
import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.EntityManager;
import jakarta.persistence.Id;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Setter;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.DataJpaTest;

import java.io.Serial;

import static com.querydsl.core.types.PathMetadataFactory.forVariable;
import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat;

@DataJpaTest
class CaseBuilderTest {

  @Autowired
  private EntityManager em;

  @Test
  void test() {

    // given
    em.persist(new TestEntity(1L, "A003", "Description ..."));
    em.persist(new TestEntity(2L, "B538", "Description ..."));

    // when
    var qTE = QTestEntity.testEntity;
    var query = new JPAQuery<TestDto>(em);
    var result = query.select(new QTestDto(qTE.id,
                            Expressions.cases()
                                       .when(qTE.code.startsWith("A"))
                                       .then(TestType.GOOD)
                                       .otherwise(TestType.BAD)))
                      .from(qTE)
                      .fetch();

    // then
    assertThat(result).hasSize(2);
  }

  @Getter
  @Setter
  public static class TestDto {
    private Long id;
    private TestType type;

    @QueryProjection
    public TestDto(Long id, TestType type) {
      this.id = id;
      this.type = type;
    }
  }


  @Entity
  @AllArgsConstructor
  @NoArgsConstructor
  public static class TestEntity {
    @Id
    @Column
    private Long id;
    @Column
    private String code;
    @Column
    private String description;
  }


  public enum TestType {
    GOOD,
    BAD;
  }


  // Generated
  public static class QTestEntity extends EntityPathBase<TestEntity> {
    @Serial
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    public static final QTestEntity testEntity = new QTestEntity("testEntity");
    public final StringPath code = createString("code");
    public final StringPath description = createString("description");
    public final NumberPath<Long> id = createNumber("id", Long.class);

    public QTestEntity(String variable) {
      super(TestEntity.class, forVariable(variable));
    }

    public QTestEntity(Path<? extends TestEntity> path) {
      super(path.getType(), path.getMetadata());
    }

    public QTestEntity(PathMetadata metadata) {
      super(TestEntity.class, metadata);
    }
  }

  // Generated
  public static class QTestDto extends ConstructorExpression<TestDto> {

    @Serial
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public QTestDto(com.querydsl.core.types.Expression<Long> id, com.querydsl.core.types.Expression<TestType> type) {
      super(TestDto.class, new Class<?>[] {long.class, TestType.class}, id, type);
    }

  }


}

What am I doing wrong?
